# Checking whether a column has proper decimal number for special case

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe (input_dataframe), which looks like as below:

```
id        test_column
1           0.25
2           1.1
3           12
4           test
5           1.3334
6           12.0
```

I want to add a column result, which put values 1 if test_column has a decimal value and 0 if test_column has any other value. data type of test_column is string. Below is the expected output:

```
id        test_column      result
1           0.25              1
2           1.1               1
3           12                0
4           test              0
5           1.3334            1
6           12.0              1
```

I have below code for this operation:

```
import decimal
from pyspark.sql.types import IntType

def is_valid_decimal(s):
    try:            
        return (0 if decimal.Decimal(val)._isinteger() else 1)
    except decimal.InvalidOperation:
        return 0

# register the UDF for usage
sqlContext.udf.register("is_valid_decimal", is_valid_decimal, IntType())

# Using the UDF
df.withColumn("result", is_valid_decimal("test_column"))
```

However this code is not working, when decimal values are like: **12.0 or 12.00 or 12.000**
Is there a way this can be achieved in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned it's a string column, so, I tired using regular expression. hope it helps,

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
>>> import re
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'0.25'),(2,'1.1'),(3,'12'),(4,'test'),(5,'1.3334'),(6,'12.0')],['id','test_col'])
>>> df.show()
+---+--------+
| id|test_col|
+---+--------+
|  1|    0.25|
|  2|     1.1|
|  3|      12|
|  4|    test|
|  5|  1.3334|
|  6|    12.0|
+---+--------+
>>> udf1 = F.udf(lambda x : 1 if re.match('^\d*[.]\d*$',x) else 0,IntegerType())
>>> df = df.withColumn('result',udf1(df.test_col))
>>> df.show()
+---+--------+------+
| id|test_col|result|
+---+--------+------+
|  1|    0.25|     1|
|  2|     1.1|     1|
|  3|      12|     0|
|  4|    test|     0|
|  5|  1.3334|     1|
|  6|    12.0|     1|
+---+--------+------+
```